# Java uninstall problems

Tags: java, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall all java.
I am getting an error message saying that I have broken packages.
Whey I try `sudo apt-get install -f`
I get a message saying that errors were encountered:

```
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions?

Here is what I get when the system proposes to repair:

```
(Reading database ... 221624 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/java-7-openjdk/management/jmxremote.access', which is different from other instances of package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ca-certificates-java:
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1) | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 is not installed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java6-installer which provides java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 which provides java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 which provides java6-runtime-headless is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 2):

I rebooted and went into recovery mode by selecting **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** in the GRUB menu and choosing the (Recovery) version of the newest kernel.

In recovery mode, I chose the option to repair packages and this solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg -P /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1_amd64.deb
```

Then retry:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just before reading your answer, I rebooted and went into advanced options in the Grub. I chose the option to repair packages and this solved my problems.

Comment: @L-ETrudeau If that solved your problem, please post it as an answer to your own question, so that other users in the future will be able to solve the same issue just by reading your post. Thank you